# Are static global variables in CPython unsafe?

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, cpython

In one C++ source file that I'm wrapping in a python function, someone has included the following:

```
namespace some_namespace 
{ 
  static double some_double; 
}

float function_that_uses_some_double(float input) { 
  // implementation
  return result; 
}
```

The static global `some_double` is only ever used inside the function, so if I wrap this in a CPython function and call it in single-threaded code, the variable will only ever be used by one function at a time. It's ugly, but no problem there. My question is what happens if I use:

1. the `threading` module, or
2. the `multiprocessing` module.

When I have multiple processes and / or threads using this module, will they interfere with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the threading module, then all functions will simply share that global variable.  Threads in python are switched between bytecode boundaries, so locking is a non-issue.

If you use the multiprocessing module, things are different and it depends a bit on your usage of multiprocessing.  Python starts with a single process so, there is only one copy of the global variable.  The value of that variable when you start using multiprocessing (i.e. forking new python processes from the main process) will be copied into the subprocesses (tasks), but those processes will each have their own copy of the global variable.

If you get tricky and set up a shared memory segment (mmap with MAP_SHARED) and the variable is a pointer, then the location pointed to will be shared and you'll need to use locking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to change some_double (which I assume you are because it's not a const variable), then you will have to do some kind of locking (e.g. mutex) if you use multiple threads.

Comment: That wasn't the question. The fact that the functions are only called from CPython (with its infamous GIL) may change a lot. And you did not adress the multiprocessing either.

Comment: I think that if your thread creation is in Python which in turn calls your CPython function then the locking (via the GIL) is done automatically for you by Python.  But if you create threads inside your C++ code, you have to acquire, lock, release the GIL yourself.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Python multiprocesssing module.

Comment: the threads would only be created in python. Each of them may invoke this function, though.